# Given $f(x,y,z)=xy^2z$ find the the max value such that the point $(x,y,z)$ is located in the part of the plane $x+y+z=4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, gradient-descent

> Given $f(x,y,z)=xy^2z$ find the the max value such that the point $(x,y,z)$ is located in the part of the plane $x+y+z=4$ which is in the first octant ($x>0, y>0, z>0$) of the coordinates.

I think Lagrange multipliers can be used here.

We can say that $x+y+z=4$ is the restriction. Let $g=x+y+z-4$. Then:
$$
\nabla f= \lambda\nabla g\\
\nabla f=\langle y^2z,2yxz,xy^2 \rangle\\
\nabla g=\langle 1,1,1 \rangle
$$
It follows that:
$$
\begin{cases}
y^2z=\lambda\\
2yxz=\lambda\\
xy^2=\lambda
\end{cases}
$$
Because $x>0, y>0, z>0$ we can solve the system and get:
$$
z=x,\quad y=2x
$$
Finally, we can rewrite the restriction as:
$$
x+2x+x=4 \Rightarrow x=1, y=2, z=1
$$

Is my usage of Lagrange method correct? Can this problem also be solved without Lagrange method by finding the max value using min/max theorems for functions with 2 variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct, it might be worth checking this is a maximum though.  You could solve it by writing $z = 4 - x - y$, and writing $f$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ only, then minimising with respect to them, but I'd personally go with Lagrange multipliers first.

Comment: Aren't we guaranteed by Lagrange multipliers that the point we got is the maximum?

Comment: We're guaranteed it's a stationary point, but it could be a maximum, minimum or saddle point

Comment: How can I prove that it's indeed a max point? The only way we learnt to do this I think is by second derivative test. I just did it on $f$ but the test returned $0$ which means we can't reach a conclusion

Comment: The second derivative test is the right idea, but you should get a matrix as the second derivative, and you'd need to show it's negative definite.

Comment: I didn't understand the matrix part. What I did was: $f_{xx}=0, f_{yy}=2xz, f_{xy}^2=0 \Rightarrow D=0\cdot 2xz-0=0$ which means that the test failed

Answer (score 1):

> Can this problem also be solved without Lagrange method by finding the max value using min/max theorems for functions with 2 variables?

Yes;  since this constraint surface is relatively simple, we can in fact eliminate one variable and solve directly in terms of $x$ and $y$.  On the plane we have $z = 4 - x - y$, and so the restriction of $f$ to the given plane is
$$
\bar{f}(x,y) = f(x,y,4-x-y) = xy^2(4-x-y) = 4 xy^2 - x^2 y^2 - x y^3.
$$
Taking the gradient of $\bar{f}$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ we obtain
$$
\vec{\nabla} \bar{f} = (4y^2 - 2xy^2 - y^3) \hat{\imath} + (8xy - 2x^2y - 3xy^2) \hat{\jmath} = y^2 (4 - 2x - y) \hat{\imath} + xy (8 - 2x - 3y) \hat{\jmath} 
$$
Since we are restricting to $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, this implies that the extremum occurs at
$$
\begin{align*}
2x + y - 4 &= 0 \\
2x + 3y - 8 &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
which can easily be solved to find that $x = 1$, $y = 2$ as you found above.

Answer (score 1):

By letting $y=4-x-z$, we consider the function $g(x,z)=xz(4-x-z)^2$ in the compact set given by the triangle $T$ of vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,4)$ and $(4,0)$. Note that the continuous (and differentiable) function $g$ is zero on the boundary of $T$ and it is positive inside. So, by Weierstrass theorem, the maximum value of $g$ is attained at some critical point inside $T$. By computing the partial derivative $g_x$ and $g_y$ it is easy to see that there is just one critical point inside $T$: if $(x,z)$ is inside $T$ then
$$(g_x,g_y)=(z (x+z-4)(3x + z-4),x (x+z-4)(x+3z-4))=(0,0)\implies (x,z)=(1,1).$$
Therefore  $(1,4-1-1,1)=(1,2,1)$ is a maximum point (the same of yours).

Comment: By equating the partial derivatives to zero, didn't you just find the stationary point? Don't we need to use the second derivative test to determine that it's indeed a max value?

Comment: In this case it is not necessary. By Weierstrass we know there is a maximum inside (which has to be a critical point). But in this case, inside,  there is a unique critical point. So it has be the maximum.

Comment: Did you choose the vertices because we know that the function is restricted to the first octant?

Comment: Yes, $x>0$, $z>0$ and $y=4-x-z>0$ give you the interior of the triangle $T$.

Comment: How did you get the vertices? If I plug in $x=0, z=0$ in the constraint equation I get $y=0$, if I plug in $y=0,z=0$ I get $x=4$. But how did you get  the third point $(0,0)$?

Comment: The constraints with respect to the variables $x$ and $z$ are $x>0$, $z>0$ and $4-x-z>0$. These 3 linear inequalities give you the triangle $T$. By intersecting the lines $x=0$ and $4=x+z$ we obtain the vertex $x=0$ and $z=4$. Similarly for other two points. Any more doubts?

Comment: It's not that I have doubts I just don't understand how to get the 3rd point $(0,0)$

Comment: Ah!  Then intersect $x=0$ and $z=0$ (then $y=4>0$).

Comment: So just to make sure I understood this correctly: in order to get $(4,0)$ we assume $x=0,y=0$ and then plug them into the constraint equation.               In order to get $(0,4)$ we assume $z=0,y=0$ and then plug them into the constraint equation.  Lastly in order to get $(0,0)$ we assume $z=0,x=0$ and plug them into $g$?

Comment: Yes, if $(4,0)$ means $z=4$ and $x=0$ and if $(0,4)$ means $x=4$ and $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
$$xy^2z=\frac{1}{4}\left(2x\cdot y\cdot y\cdot2z\right)\leq\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2x+y+y+2z}{4}\right)^4=4.$$
The equality occurs for $x=z=1$ and $y=2$, which gives the answer: $4$.

Done!